# How to remove class sibling element with data-attribute as trigger

Tags: jquery, siblings

I'm trying to make simple tabbing with data-attribute as trigger.

When I click .tab-list it should be give class active with all element if match with data-tabbing. But I have problem when removing sibling of .tab-panel, I'm trying to find('data') to remove class, I though it will work

How I can remove class from .tab-panel with data-attribut as trigger

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  tab();
});


function tab() {
  var tablist = $('.tab-heading .tab-list');

  tablist.on('click', function() {
    var tablistData = $(this).attr('data-tabbing');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    var listContent = $('.tab-content .tab-panel');
    console.log(listContent.length);
    listContent.find("[data-tabbing='" + tablistData + "']").addClass('active');
    listContent.siblings().find('data').removeClass('active');

  });
}
```

```css
.tab-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-heading {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-heading .tab-list {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-heading .tab-list.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-content {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-content .tab-head-sp.active {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-content .list-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.tab-wrapper .tab-content .list-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrapper">
  <div class="tab-heading">
   <div class="tab-list" data-tabbing="item-1">item-1</div>
   <div class="tab-list" data-tabbing="item-2">item-2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-panel">
    <div class="tab-head-sp" data-tabbing="item-1">heading-1</div>
    <div class="list-content" data-tabbing="item-1">
     <p>content-1</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-panel">
    <div class="tab-head-sp" data-tabbing="item-2">heading-2</div>
    <div class="list-content" data-tabbing="item-2">
     <p>content-2</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `active` class from children of `listContent` before you set it again.

```
listContent.children(".active").removeClass("active")
listContent.find("[data-tabbing='" + tablistData + "']").addClass('active');
```

Another way is again to remove the class before we set it, but if you want to use `.find()` try `listContent.siblings().find("div[data!='"+tablistData+"']").removeClass('active')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  tab();
});


function tab() {
  var tablist = $('.tab-heading .tab-list');

  tablist.on('click', function() {
    var tablistData = $(this).attr('data-tabbing');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    var listContent = $('.tab-content .tab-panel');
    //listContent.children(".active").removeClass("active")
    listContent.siblings().find("div[data!='"+tablistData+"']").removeClass('active')
    listContent.find("[data-tabbing='" + tablistData + "']").addClass('active');


  });
}
```

```css
.tab-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-heading {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-heading .tab-list {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-heading .tab-list.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-content {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-content .tab-head-sp.active {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-content .list-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-wrapper .tab-content .list-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrapper">
  <div class="tab-heading">
    <div class="tab-list" data-tabbing="item-1">item-1</div>
    <div class="tab-list" data-tabbing="item-2">item-2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-panel">
      <div class="tab-head-sp" data-tabbing="item-1">heading-1</div>
      <div class="list-content" data-tabbing="item-1">
        <p>konten-1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-panel">
      <div class="tab-head-sp" data-tabbing="item-2">heading-2</div>
      <div class="list-content" data-tabbing="item-2">
        <p>konten-1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was great help.
why it didnt work when I try to select from its sibling?

Comment: I think it had something to do with your selector of your `.find()`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now I have alternative solution if facing same cases, Thank you for explanation brother